# Remove features from Google data object before assigning to Google map object

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I would like to filter features before assigning to map object.

```
var temp = new google.maps.Data();
temp.loadGeoJson(URL); or temp.addGeoJson(geojsonDATA);
```

WANT TO DO FILTER HERE. Have to remove few features.

trying to do this, but it is not at all executing the loop,

```
temp.forEach(function(feature){
    FILTER LOGIC
});

temp.setMap(gmapObj);
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will depend on how you add the features.

When you use `loadGeoJson` you must run the function in the callback of loadGeoJson(loadGeoJson runs asynchronously).

When you use `addGeoJson` execute it after the call of addGeoJson

### 2 examples(removing the letter o from a string drawn via polygons)

**using loadGeoJson:**

```js
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -28, lng: 137}
  });
  var temp = new google.maps.Data();
  temp.loadGeoJson('https://storage.googleapis.com/maps-devrel/google.json',{},function(){
    temp.forEach(function(feature){
      if(feature.getProperty('letter')==='o'){//your condition
        temp.remove(feature);
      }
    });
  });

  temp.setMap(map);
}
```

```css
html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=initMap"></script>
```

**using addGeoJson:**

```js
var json={
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "letter": "G",
        "color": "blue",
        "rank": "7",
        "ascii": "71"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [123.61, -22.14], [122.38, -21.73], [121.06, -21.69], [119.66, -22.22], [119.00, -23.40],
            [118.65, -24.76], [118.43, -26.07], [118.78, -27.56], [119.22, -28.57], [120.23, -29.49],
            [121.77, -29.87], [123.57, -29.64], [124.45, -29.03], [124.71, -27.95], [124.80, -26.70],
            [124.80, -25.60], [123.61, -25.64], [122.56, -25.64], [121.72, -25.72], [121.81, -26.62],
            [121.86, -26.98], [122.60, -26.90], [123.57, -27.05], [123.57, -27.68], [123.35, -28.18],
            [122.51, -28.38], [121.77, -28.26], [121.02, -27.91], [120.49, -27.21], [120.14, -26.50],
            [120.10, -25.64], [120.27, -24.52], [120.67, -23.68], [121.72, -23.32], [122.43, -23.48],
            [123.04, -24.04], [124.54, -24.28], [124.58, -23.20], [123.61, -22.14]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "letter": "o",
        "color": "red",
        "rank": "15",
        "ascii": "111"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [128.84, -25.76], [128.18, -25.60], [127.96, -25.52], [127.88, -25.52], [127.70, -25.60],
            [127.26, -25.79], [126.60, -26.11], [126.16, -26.78], [126.12, -27.68], [126.21, -28.42],
            [126.69, -29.49], [127.74, -29.80], [128.80, -29.72], [129.41, -29.03], [129.72, -27.95],
            [129.68, -27.21], [129.33, -26.23], [128.84, -25.76]
          ],
          [
            [128.45, -27.44], [128.32, -26.94], [127.70, -26.82], [127.35, -27.05], [127.17, -27.80],
            [127.57, -28.22], [128.10, -28.42], [128.49, -27.80], [128.45, -27.44]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "letter": "o",
        "color": "yellow",
        "rank": "15",
        "ascii": "111"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [131.87, -25.76], [131.35, -26.07], [130.95, -26.78], [130.82, -27.64], [130.86, -28.53],
            [131.26, -29.22], [131.92, -29.76], [132.45, -29.87], [133.06, -29.76], [133.72, -29.34],
            [134.07, -28.80], [134.20, -27.91], [134.07, -27.21], [133.81, -26.31], [133.37, -25.83],
            [132.71, -25.64], [131.87, -25.76]
          ],
          [
            [133.15, -27.17], [132.71, -26.86], [132.09, -26.90], [131.74, -27.56], [131.79, -28.26],
            [132.36, -28.45], [132.93, -28.34], [133.15, -27.76], [133.15, -27.17]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "letter": "g",
        "color": "blue",
        "rank": "7",
        "ascii": "103"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [138.12, -25.04], [136.84, -25.16], [135.96, -25.36], [135.26, -25.99], [135, -26.90],
            [135.04, -27.91], [135.26, -28.88], [136.05, -29.45], [137.02, -29.49], [137.81, -29.49],
            [137.94, -29.99], [137.90, -31.20], [137.85, -32.24], [136.88, -32.69], [136.45, -32.36],
            [136.27, -31.80], [134.95, -31.84], [135.17, -32.99], [135.52, -33.43], [136.14, -33.76],
            [137.06, -33.83], [138.12, -33.65], [138.86, -33.21], [139.30, -32.28], [139.30, -31.24],
            [139.30, -30.14], [139.21, -28.96], [139.17, -28.22], [139.08, -27.41], [139.08, -26.47],
            [138.99, -25.40], [138.73, -25.00 ], [138.12, -25.04]
          ],
          [
            [137.50, -26.54], [136.97, -26.47], [136.49, -26.58], [136.31, -27.13], [136.31, -27.72],
            [136.58, -27.99], [137.50, -28.03], [137.68, -27.68], [137.59, -26.78], [137.50, -26.54]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "letter": "l",
        "color": "green",
        "rank": "12",
        "ascii": "108"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [140.14,-21.04], [140.31,-29.42], [141.67,-29.49], [141.59,-20.92], [140.14,-21.04]
          ]
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "letter": "e",
        "color": "red",
        "rank": "5",
        "ascii": "101"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [144.14, -27.41], [145.67, -27.52], [146.86, -27.09], [146.82, -25.64], [146.25, -25.04],
            [145.45, -24.68], [144.66, -24.60], [144.09, -24.76], [143.43, -25.08], [142.99, -25.40],
            [142.64, -26.03], [142.64, -27.05], [142.64, -28.26], [143.30, -29.11], [144.18, -29.57],
            [145.41, -29.64], [146.46, -29.19], [146.64, -28.72], [146.82, -28.14], [144.84, -28.42],
            [144.31, -28.26], [144.14, -27.41]
          ],
          [
            [144.18, -26.39], [144.53, -26.58], [145.19, -26.62], [145.72, -26.35], [145.81, -25.91],
            [145.41, -25.68], [144.97, -25.68], [144.49, -25.64], [144, -25.99], [144.18, -26.39]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: {lat: -28, lng: 137}
  });
  var temp = new google.maps.Data();
  temp.addGeoJson(json);
  temp.forEach(function(feature){
      if(feature.getProperty('letter')==='o'){//your condition
        temp.remove(feature);
      }
  });
  temp.setMap(map);
}
```

```css
html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: One more ques, 
can we add circle config during callback of loadgeoJSON()     function.google.maps.Circle({
                         strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                         strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                         strokeWeight: 2,
                         fillColor: '#FF0000',
                         fillOpacity: 0.35,
                         map: gmapObj,
                         center: LatLng,
                         radius: Math.pow(2, feature.getProperty('mag')) / 2
                       });

Comment: geoJson/google.maps.Data doesn't support circles. But you may e.g. use a Point , provide the options(e.g. radius) via the properties, and in the callback remove the point and add a Circle (based on the properties) to the map.